# From a file extract a substring from a line in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep, substring

I need help to get a substring from a file. I have two variable, the IP source and IP destination address. I need to validate lines in file containing the two IP's and get the port of the source address.

This is the input file:

```
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.155.58363 > 239.255.255.254.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
 15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.155.58363 > 239.255.255.254.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.131.58363 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
   0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
15:29:18.164566 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 2394, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 125)
    10.0.0.155.80 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 97
    0x0000:  4600 0024 0000 0000 0102 3ad3 0a00 0000  F..$......:.....
    0x0010:  e000 0001 9404 0000 1101 ebfe 0000 0000  ................
    0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
   0x0020:  0300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       ..............
```

The two vars:

```
ips=10.0.0.155

ipd=239.255.255.254
```

The output result must be:

```
58363
```

This is the port of the IP source address `10.0.0.155.58363`.

Comment: what is this output result? not make any sense..

Comment: Is the port of the ip adreess source 10.0.0.155.58363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with `grep`:

```
$ ips=10.0.0.155

$ ipd=239.255.255.254

$ grep -Po "(?<=$ips\.)\d+(?= > $ipd)" file
58363
58363
```

File has repeated line so pipe to `uniq`:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=$ips\.)\d+(?= > $ipd)" file | uniq
58363
```

---

Or using a capture group with `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/'"$ipd"'/s/.*'"$ips"'\.\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' file
58363
58363

$ sed -n '/'"$ipd"'/s/.*'"$ips"'\.\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p' file | uniq
58363
```

---

Or in `awk`:

```
$ awk -v s=$ips -v d=$ipd '$1~s && $3~d {sub(/.*\./,"",$1);print $1}' file
58363
58363

$ awk -v s=$ips -v d=$ipd '$1~s&&$3~d&&!u[$0]++{sub(/.*\./,"",$1);print $1}' file
58363
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help you. You can replace IP with your variable.

```
[spatel@mg0008 ~]$ grep 10.0.0.155.58363 /tmp/outputfile.txt
    10.0.0.155.58363 > 239.255.255.254.1900: UDP, length 97
    10.0.0.155.58363 > 239.255.255.254.1900: UDP, length 97
```

More trimming...

```
[spatel@mg0008 tmp]$ grep 10.0.0.155.58363 /tmp/outputfile.txt | awk -F'.' '{print $5}' | awk '{print $1}'
58363
58363
```

Comment: This doesn't check the line for the destination IP so will have false matches and the port is unknown and you have hard coded it into the search also `grep | awk | awk` isn't necessary. This isn't a solution to the given problem.